# Comfortable typing on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, display, macos

I love my macbook pro, I have the 17" version that came out several months ago.  So I can take it with me wherever, at my desk, friend's place, on the couch.. and have a full development environment with the big screen.

Problem is my wrists scrape against the edge on the bottom of the keyboard.  I'm on the computer a lot and this is starting to really bother me.  Normal desktop (detached) keyboards don't have this edge...  I actually bought Apple's wireless beautiful little keyboard, but then the issue is the screen gets too far away if I have to put the wireless keyboard in front of the laptop's built-in keyboard.  And working on my lap, which I absolutely love, is much less comfortable.

What's the solution?  Is there a nice thin padding product I can buy for the bottom of the macbook pro?  Is there a stand or way I can position the laptop so I can use the wireless keyboard without the screen being too far away?  Is that even possible while the laptop and wireless keyboard are on my lap?

***UPDATE***: I guess the Apple wireless keyboard is a little problematic to use on my lap because it doesn't have a trackpad... so I'll constantly be moving my arm far to move the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cheap alternative to the [bookstand](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000OOYECC) + external keyboard combination already mentioned, I find it very useful to simply wedge a small flat object (I use a marker) under the back of the laptop while it's resting on a desk. This puts the keyboard at a slight angle, which I found much more comfortable for prolonged typing (keeps the wrist from pressing on the edge too hard).

It also provides some extra ventilation (that's why I originally did it), as the wrist rests can get uncomfortably hot sometimes on my MBP.

You can also use an external monitor with your external keyboard in front of it and leave the laptop somewhere to the side to use as 2nd screen.

Comment: I love that mStand!  But I realize I couldn't use it on my lap, assuming I could feel comfortable balancing it on my lap anyway.. because I need a mouse and the wireless keyboard doesn't have a trackpad.  Also great idea about the small flat object in the back of the MBP.  You know what would be interesting for me is to have a wireless keyboard and a wireless monitor (not even necessary to be wireless) that I can balance on my lap.  Then I could have a much more comfortable experience.  But the keyboard would have to have a trackpad...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put the laptop on a bookstand? that's what I do with my MB.
typing while the laptop is on the bookstand might not suit everyone's taste, but you can easily slide a keyboard right in front of it, leaving the screen where it needs to be!

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I very much like that mStand Ingmar posted instead of a bookstand.  The keyboard doesn't go underneath, but because the mStand is at an angle the screen doesn't appear as far away.

Comment: ah, I see. so the real issue is being able to keep it on your lap! That makes things much harder. Isn't a 17'' a bit heavy for something like that? Anyway, I'd be interested if someone else has some different solutions.

Comment: ideally I'd love to continue using it on my lap, not heavy at all right now.  But I'd be happy just having a good portable solution even requiring a desk.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if [this](http://store.moshimonde.com/macbook/palmguard.html) will work for you, but check it out. I haven't used it before, but we have the MBP keyboard protector and it is a great quality product.

Comment: Very nice, I actually would love something to protect my keyboard and palm rest and trackpad.  Not sure this would solve my wrist comfort issues though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure that it has padding...